# Why am I not getting any MouseMove events while the mouse button is pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a `MainPanel` which contains `myElement`. When I press the mouse button on the panel, and move it over `myElement` while still holding the button, `myElement_MouseMove` does not get called.

```
private void myElement_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myElementStatus_lbl.Text = "I SEE YOU";
}
```

It works when I'm not holding the mouse button down.

How do I detect mouse movement when the mouse button is down?

```
this.MainPanel.Controls.Add(this.myElement);
this.MainPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(182, 84);
this.MainPanel.Name = "MainPanel";
this.MainPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(604, 309);
this.MainPanel.TabIndex = 0;

// 
// myElement
// 
this.myElement.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 67);
this.myElement.Name = "myElement";
this.myElement.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
this.myElement.TabIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think its because drag events occur during mouse pressed. So when your holding the mouse button and the mouse enters a control, [drag enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event takes place.

You can detect mouse movements using one of the drag events. [DragEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [DragOver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragover%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [DragLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Edit: [DoDragDrop disables MouseMove Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664905/dodragdrop-disables-mousemove-events)